# Matlab: Solve 2nd order ODE using anonymous function

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, ode45

To solve ODE below with matlab

[image]

```
t = 0:.01:20;
x0 = [0 0]';
xdot = @(t,x) [0 1; 0 0] * x;
ode45(@(t,x) xdot(x(1), x(2)),t,x0)
```

I get this error:

> Error using odearguments (line 91) @(T,X)XDOT(X(1),X(2)) must return a
>   column vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x0` is a `2 by 1` matrix, precise this in your function handle

```
xdot = @(t,x) [0 1; 0 0] * x; ---> xdot = @(t,x) [0 1; 0 0] * [x(1);x(2)];
```

since `xdot` is already defined as a function you don't need `@` to pass it in `ode45`

The code is as follow

```
t = 0:.01:20;
x0 = [0 0]';
xdot = @(t,x) [0 1; 0 0] * [x(1);x(2)];
ode45(xdot,t,x0)
```